# VBA - Conditional Formatting Multiple Ranges of Cells and Looping

Tags: vba, excel, loops, macros, conditional-formatting

I am creating a Master Schedule for work and am trying to display information so it is very intuitive to the user.

So... we would like to be able to Highlight Cells J4:L4 when a date is entered in Cell K4. Then, we want to loop it for Rows 4 through 2500 and Columns M:0, P:R, S:U, etc.... I have the following Macro written but it is only highlighting the first Row. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
    Sub Highlight()
    '
    ' Highlight Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R
    '
    Dim kRange As Range, k As Integer, aaaFormat As FormatCondition
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> Sheet1.Name Then Exit Sub
    For k = 4 To 2500
        Set kRange = Range("=$J4:$L4")
        If kRange.FormatConditions.Count <> 0 Then
            kRange.FormatConditions.Delete
        Else
            Set aaaFormat = kRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, "=$K4<>0")
            aaaFormat.Interior.Color = 15773696
        End If
    Next k
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not creating the CF rule for all the cells at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are cycling through the loop, you need to adjust the range the CF rule will govern as well as the formula that determines its outcome.

```
'this,
Set kRange = Range("$J4:$L4")
'becomes,
Set kRange = Range("$J"& k & ":$L"& k)
'and this,
Set aaaFormat = kRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, "=$K4<>0")
'becomes,
Set aaaFormat = kRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, "=$K" & k & "<>0")
```

However, since you've already made the row relative and the column absolute, you can simply write the CF to the entire range.

```
Sub Highlight()
    ' Highlight Macro
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R

    With Sheet1.Range("J4:L2500")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$K4<>0")
            .Interior.Color = 15773696
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not creating a CF for all the cells at once because I need it to be individualized by row when a cell within each row has the information input. I am also trying to keep the file size as low as possible. I apologize but I am still fairly new at this, would you be able to clarify or further explain the Macro above. I was only able to get it to remove the existing Conditional Formatting for Column J4.

Comment: Which one? The changes to your code or the one I provided below it? btw, a single CF rule for a large number of rows is far less calculation intensive than many CF rules governing one row each.

Comment: If the single CF rule is less intensive, can you explain how to do that. - I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there a way I can e-mail the file to you so I can be certain I am explaining what I am trying to do correctly?

Comment: I GOT IT! Thanks for your help. I would still appreciate the opportunity to send you the file and ask your opinion on a few things. It will be the most robust scheduling system I have built.

Comment: Sorry to say but I really do not do one-on-one evaluations. That isn't why I'm here and it's not in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)'s mission statement. With that said, I'm glad to hear you got sorted out and I look forward to participating in any future questions you post.